# Debug Azure Function in Visual Studio

Tags: azure-functions

I initially created my  Azure Function as dotnet-isolated with dotnet 5. Unfortunately, due to [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/532) I've had to downgrade it to in-process and dotnet core 3.1.

My problem is VS doesn't seem to know it's a Function App. It's set as the startup project but when I hit F5 to debug I get the message:

> A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started
> directly

Content of the cs proj file is as follows:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
      <UserSecretsId>...</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="local.settings.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions" Version="2.2.0" />
    etc...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference...
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Anyone know what VS uses to decide the library should be run as a function app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was missing package reference to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions. Once I added the following to the csproj file then I was able to debug:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
```